# Управление глагола ПЕРЕЛЕЗАТЬ

Tags: глаголы, управление

На экскурсии увидел объявление-предупреждение:

> Пожалуйста, не перелезайте перила!

И подумал, что мне хочется сказать:

> Пожалуйста, не перелезайте **через** перила!

Как в данном случае правильно? Допустим только один из вариантов или оба?

Answer (score 2):

Мне тоже хочется добавить предлог ***через***, но, видимо, возможны оба варианта:

> **ПЕРЕЛЕЗТЬ,** -лезу, -лезешь; перелез, -ла, -ло; **св. 1.** *кого-что* или *через что*. Карабкаясь на что-л., переместиться на другую сторону чего-л. *П. через плетень. **П. ограду**. Ребёнок перелез через маму.* <...>
> **<Перелезать,** -аю, -аешь; **нсв**.

Источник: Большой толковый словарь ([Грамота.ру](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)).

В Нацкорпусе русского языка в подавляющем большинстве примеров с этим глаголом и его формами присутствует предлог ***через***. Интересно то, что, если его убрать, ни смысл, ни грамматика не пострадают. Но всё же что-то неуловимое будет потеряно. А иногда без предлога и не скажешь: *Ребёнок перелез маму*.
Я думаю, что в использовании предлога (там, где его может и не быть) имеет место некоторая избыточность, закрепленная в речи и не собирающаяся из нее исчезать (ведь в самой приставке ПЕРЕ уже заложен нужный смысл). Словосочетания с такой "избыточностью" всегда есть в языке, и она нисколько не мешает, а наоборот, способствует выразительности и усиливает оттенки.

> **ПЕРЕ... *приставка*. I. *(служит для образования глаг.).*** Обозначает: **1.** Направленность движения, действия через какое-л. пространство или предмет. *Перейти (улицу или через улицу); перешагнуть, перебросить (через забор).*

P. S. Перебросить забор можно, но это уже другая история...

Comment: Поисследовал управление и вижу, что частотно будет употребление с предлогом *через*, но допустим и другой вариант. Интересно, допустим без ограничений или же в частных случаях. Такой информации не нашёл.

Comment: Да, сейчас посмотрел в Нацкорпусе слово "перелез" – примеров с предлогом подавляющее большинство.